# Is it possible to do currency exchange in Antalya Airport after arrival?

Tags: money, exchange, antalya

I will fly to Antalya tomorrow and my approximated arrival time is about 10:00 P.M. local time. I will take some Pound Sterling in cash with me. The problem is that by the time I clear immigration in Antalya, it will be really late. I wonder whether or not I can exchange Pound Sterling into Turkish Lira at the airport.

Has anyone got any idea whether or not exchanging currency at Antalya Airport will be possible during late hours? Or Must I exchange it before going there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Garanti Bank provides a 24h currency exchange at the airport. They have counters in the arrival halls of terminals 1 and 2, as well as in the domestic terminal.

In addition there are plenty of ATM's. If ever the queue at the bank is too long, you can grasp some notes from a machine and exchange the Pound Sterling later on in Antalya. Note that in the city you may find better rates than at the airport.

http://www.aytport.com/en/1/5/service_companies.asp

http://www.turkeytravelplanner.com/go/med/Antalya/trans/airport.html

Comment: Nice and simple +1 :)

Comment: I wish you a pleasant trip :-)